# Video issues where screen freezes with columned blocks of pixels appearing on screen followed by computer shutting down

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, screen, crash, gpu-driver

My computer freezes and then shuts down randomly. It happens couple of times within an 8 hour work-day. It would run fine without crashing over weekends. I started having this problem two weeks ago, so I did a fresh re-install of 16.04 where i wiped my root directory, but kept the home directory from old setup. I was originally running 16.04 too.

I don't have a lot of programs running when it happens. Just the terminal and chrome. May be thunderbird and sublime sometimes, but other than that the there is nothing else running on the system.

I am not sure where to look for the solution. I have attached a pic to better describe the state of my pc when it happens.

EDIT 1: I looked into my user logs at /var/log/syslog and there are NO errors or warnings when the system freezes or crashes. I can only see some errors/warnings during the bootup.

EDIT 2: Ran a memtest86 overnight and there were NO failures. All 7 tests that ran passed. No tests failed. Currently running an additional 12V fan inside my tower to keep the CPU cool. My computer still crashed after I installed the external fan, but it crashed only once in 4 hours (which is a good uptime)

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu does not have a "random shutdown" feature (who would want that?)...but your motherboard does, to prevent thermal damage.  Check your logs around the time of a shutdown for warnings or errors. And look up how to prevent thermal failure.

Comment: How can I check the logs around the time of a shutdown? My computer is totally unusable when it freezes and no peripherals work. Are the the logs persistent? Would be great if you could point me to the log location/

Comment: Logs are persistent, and located at /var/log/syslog. You are looking for lines *before* shutdown like 'Warning:' and 'Error:'. There may be some, there may not. This is secondary - your main problem seems to be overheating which is not really an Ubuntu issue.

Comment: thanks, but i m not seeing any warning/errors in the logs before shutdown. Shutdown happened before 11:44am (based on uptime calculation) and I am seeing a bunch of errors/warnings at 11:44 which I believe is expected. How do you know for certain that it's an overheating issue.

Comment: the computer does make a click sound right when it freezes. It's the same click sound i hear when i reboot my machine using the power button.

Comment: I think it's overheating because there are no other errors in the log, and your symptoms are *classic* overheating. As I mentioned, Ubuntu does NOT  have a shutdown-without-logging or reboot-without-logging-feature...so your problem is not originating in software. Therefore your problem is originating in hardware.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72059/discussion-between-numbersinmyhead-and-user535733).

Comment: Have you run a memory check (memtest86) or such?

Comment: no, i haven't. Currently I have installed an additional cooling fan inside my tower. It's  a 12 V fan and quite strong. Will run the memtest if it fails again.

Comment: @user3169 i ran an overnight memtest86 and there were 7 passes and 0 failures. I doubt it is a memory issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing a 12V fan blowing over the CPU has helped and computer is running as expected. No crashes anymore. Just had to make sure the fan is pointed directly where the CPU core is.